# Closing A Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I received help yesterday from a few wonderful users and thought I would reach out again with another issue I am experiencing.  I have always used `this.Close();` to close my `winform` but in this instance I am returning the value from a variable and utilizing `this` to do such so when my code hits thett `this.Close();` the `winform` is not closed as the `this` refers to something else

(or at least I think that is what the issue is) - what I am after is a way to close my `winform TestData` when the code hits the `this.Close();`

What is currently happening is an endless loop of the code that starts with

```
if (spreadsheetimported == true)
{
```

--if I need to show additional code I can--

```
public partial class TestData : Form
{
    public CancelFileImport p1;

    public TestData(CancelFileImport _p1)
    {
        p1 = _p1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
    private void Testing_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            if (ssi == true)
            {
                CancelFileImport CFI = new CancelFileImport(this);
                CFI.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                CFI.ShowDialog();

                if (cnclsve)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    //user did not mean to cancel the save
                    //go back to save method
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public partial class CancelFileImport : Form
{
    public static TestData _p1;

    public CancelFileImport(TestData p1)
    {
        _p1 = p1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public CancelFileImport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _p1.ssi = true;
        this.Close();
    }
    private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _p1.ssi = false;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not call Close() in an event handler for the FormClosing event.  All hell breaks loose when that causes the FormClosing event to fire again.  In this case a dialog that shows over and over again.  Eventually the exception for which this site was named, your index finger runs out before it can get that far :)  The only appropriate thing to do is set e.Cancel = true when you intend to *not* close the form.

Comment: @HansPassant - so remove the `this.Closee();` and replace with `e.Cancel = true;`

Comment: Yes, think about it. Form_Closing is called when your form is ready to.....? No point in telling the engine, hey I want to close. On the contrary you could tell the engine that you don't want anymore to close the form with _e.Cancel = true;_

Comment: @Aldert - I call `Testing_FormClosing` as the `FormClosing` event

Comment: I want to close both `CancelFileImport` and `TestData` if `cnclsve == true` if I change the syntax to `e.Cancel = true;` The form 'TestData' is never closed?

Comment: First, set the _DialogResult_ property to the two buttons in the _CancelFileImport_ form to _DialogResult.Yes_ and _DialogResult.No_ Then read the return value from _CFI.ShowDialog_. If the return is _DialogResult.No_ then set _e.Cancel = true;_ otherwise do nothing and let the _Form_Closing_ end.

Comment: And remove the this.Close in the two click event handlers in the CancelFileImport form (the form closes automatically if a button with a DialogResult property is clicked)

Comment: @Steve - how do I set the DialogResult Property?  If I try to do DialogResult.Yes; there is compile error.

Comment: Replace this.Close(); with TestData.ActiveForm.Dispose();

Comment: @user2676140 - that got it!  Using a combination of e.Cancel = true; and TestData.ActiveForm.Dispose(); solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: @TimmyTurner - I have posted solution as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it like this

Replace `this.Close();` with `TestData.ActiveForm.Dispose();`